# android - Headless Retained Fragment vs. Class with public static variables (Global Class)

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I'm part of an Android project that uses a global class that contains public static variables, like the example below:

```
public class Globals {
    public static MyObject variable = "this is a test";
}
```

In the middle of using the application, this global variable's value will be changed let's say:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Globals.variable = new MyObject(somethingHere);
}
```

And I came across using Headless Retained Fragments from these blog posts:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments

**Problem:**
I need to have a reference of an initialized object all over the application.

**Question:**
which is better to implement, a good practice, and practical? Or is there another way I could store a reference of an object all over the application?

The global class has been used over the project, and works fine, but are there any downsides of this implementation?

Answer (score 2):

> are there any downsides of this implementation?

Memory leaks, depending on what you are storing there. Leaks are why static data members are considered poor form in classic Java, even if we tend to use them more in Android app development.

Also, this data needs to be considered a cache, one that has to be able to be lazy-created on first access. Your process can be terminated at any point (wiping out the static data member) and the user can return to any activity in your app (courtesy of the recent-tasks list). If you want this data to survive process termination, the most likely solution will be to persist it in a file, database, or `SharedPreferences`.

All that being said, a retained fragment is a per-activity solution, not a per-application solution, and so it is not a valid alternative for your scenario AFAICT.

Comment: As I have viewed the globals class, it comprises primitive data types and objects.

The value of the variable does not need to be present the next time I open the application, but the value of this variable will be changed as the user interacts with the app, like transferring from one activity to the other, and another activity will be using the value of the variable or either change it again, depending on the scenario if it needs to be changed.

Comment: @NyahahaWakoko: "the value of this variable will be changed as the user interacts with the app, like transferring from one activity to the other, and another activity will be using the value of the variable or either change it again, depending on the scenario if it needs to be changed" -- IMHO, that sounds like you should be using an event bus more than a global variable, but that's just me.

Comment: Yeah, I would love to use event bus, but the project manager does not permit me to add any other library, so I really have to code it. Worst case for me now is to follow what they have started, even though it's open to memory leaks. Any best practice or approach on this kind of problem would greatly help..

Comment: @NyahahaWakoko: " I would love to use event bus, but the project manager does not permit me to add any other library" -- `LocalBroadcastManager` is part of the Android Support package. "Any best practice or approach on this kind of problem would greatly help" -- you have not stated that there *is* a problem.